How to check current server session is forward connection or reverse connection in OPC UA C#?
I have developed OPC UA SERVER application using CSharp(C#) language. I want to know if the connection is reverse or forward in OPC UA Server.
My requirement is that the OPC UA server shall only accept ReverseHello session opening requests with “Anonymous User Identity Token” policy.
I want to differentiate whether the current seesion forward connection or reverse connection.in SessionManager_ImpersonateUser method
This method is invoked when client tries to change user identity in UAExpert.
For forward connection, the following usertoken policy shall work
anonymous
username
certificate
For reverse connection the following user token policy shall work
anonymous
Please help me with the solution!
